# Curl and file_get_contents timeouts in PHP (command line curl with same URL works normally)

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to retrieve the contents of a URL: `https://www.cyber.gov.au/`.

If I use wget or curl from the command line, all is fine. The response is almost instant.

```
$ wget https://www.cyber.gov.au/

--2020-11-17 08:47:12--  https://www.cyber.gov.au/
Resolving www.cyber.gov.au (www.cyber.gov.au)... 92.122.153.122, 92.122.153.201
Connecting to www.cyber.gov.au (www.cyber.gov.au)|92.122.153.122|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 41951 (41K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

index.html                  100%[=========================================>]  40.97K  --. KB/s    in 0.002s  

2020-11-17 08:47:13 (18.8 MB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [41951/41951]
```

However, when I try to connect to the same URL through PHP curl, it times out with the message:

```
Operation timed out after 5001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received
```

I've reduced this to a test case:

```
$handle = curl_init('https://www.cyber.gov.au/');
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36');
$output = curl_exec($handle);

echo $output;

curl_close($handle);
```

I also tried with various combinations of these additional curl settings, with no change:

```
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4); // Also tried specifying v6
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
```

It doesn't seem to be the DNS resolution time:

```
echo curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_NAMELOOKUP_TIME); // 0.012 seconds
```

I've tried this on different machines, with different versions of PHP (7.2.12 and 7.4.10), and I get the same behaviour. Other URLs, both HTTP and HTTPS, work as expected. I get the same on CLI PHP as through Apache. Trying `file_get_contents()` gives a similar result, it just times out. Adding verbose curl logging didn't provide any more information.

`curl --version` gives `curl 7.47.0` and `curl 7.58.0` on the machines I tested on.

Can anyone spot what's going on or point me in the right direction to find out more about the problem?

Comment: Not sure why, but just running it locally it seems to work fine.

Comment: How strange. Well, at least that indicates it's something to do with my PHP setup or server. Thanks for trying it, much appreciated.

Comment: Just a quick test for you, try my site https://klu.io - I use HSTS same as that site and it could be something strange there (it shouldn't make a difference but that is the only thing that is "unusual" about their site). The only other thing that I can think of is something strange with port settings. Oh or it could be attempting to block bots by checking referrer header etc. `curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.example.com');`, but I would be surprised if it was that. As it worked for @NigelRen I would start with checking ports.

Comment: Thanks. I tried a bunch more user agents and - weirdly - it worked with the standard curl one, but nothing else. I'm assuming there's some sort of security system in place looking as UAs with some exceptions ...